# Need help populating nesting arrays in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am struggling with populating nested arrays using mongoose.

I have a recipe model that looks something like this:

```
let recipeSchema = Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  description: {
    type: String,
  },

  steps: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  ingredients: [],

  reviewsArray: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review' }],

  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  postedBy: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],

  numberOfRatings: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },

  totalAddedRatings: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
  },

  reviewAverage: {
      type: Number,
      default: undefined
  },

});
```

And I also have a User model:

```
let User = Schema({

  name: {
    type: String
  },

  // The passport plugin already inputs username and password into our Schema

  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },

   password: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
   minlength: 6
   },

   userId: {
     type: String,
     default: "Empty"
   },

   tokens: [{

    access: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },

    token: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }

  }],

  profilePic: {
    type: String
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: (value) => {
        return validator.isEmail(value);
      },

      message: `{value} is not a valid email address.`
    }
  },

  admin: {
    type: Boolean,
      defualt: false
  },

  usersRecipes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe' }],

  usersReviews: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review' }],

  usersFavouriteRecipes: {
    type: Array
  },

  usersLikedRecipes: {
    type: Array
  },

  chefKarma: {
    type: Number,
    defualt: 0
  }



});
```

Whenever the user makes a new recipe, I want that recipe to also be stored in the usersRecipe array. The code where I try to do that is this:

```
router.post('/addrecipe', (req, res, next) => {

    Recipe.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        steps: req.body.steps,
        ingredients: req.body.ingredients,
        category: req.body.category,
        postedBy: req.body.postedBy
    });


    User.find({_id: req.body.postedBy})
        .populate({
            path: 'usersRecipes',
            model: 'Recipe'
        })
        .exec(function(err, docs) {});


    });
```

My code is not working as I intended though. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you are confusing population with update. If you want to insert the recipe reference in user document, you need to update the user document. `populate` only finds and fill the references with real documents, not inserts them.

Comment: If I use update, should I get rid of  usersRecipes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe' }], ?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are doing...
save a Recipe like

```
{
        name: "hot chips",
        description: "some goods",
        steps: "2",
        ingredients: "",
        category: "chips",
        postedBy: "12312312312312"
}
```

then search for user with  12312312312312 id , some user like this

```
{
   name:"farshad",
   usersRecipes: []
}
```

and then say populate usersRecipes for me...
do you get your mistake?
you dont write that Recipe id in you user document. so userRecipes is always empty... so each time, you dont get any usersRecipes.

you have two solution
1. when ever a user create a recipe, write that recipe id in usersRecipes...
you can create...

```
recipe.save().then(function(res) {
   //update user document userrecipes array
});
```

OR
2.every time you get the user, search in recipes collection for recipes with that user id

```
Users.find({id:""}).exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
//fill userrecipes
    Recipes.find()....
});
```